# Devexpress Datagrid icons images filter not displayed angular

Tags: angular, datagrid, devexpress

I have defined a filter row inside a datagrid but I cannot see the images associated with the icons present in the dropdown menu.

```
<dx-data-grid id="gridContainer" [dataSource]="orders" [showBorders]="true">
    <dxo-filter-row 
          [visible]="true">
    </dxo-filter-row>
    <dxi-column dataField="latitude" 
          caption="Latitude">
          datatype="number"
    </dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

the icons to which I refer are these

[image]

What could be the cause of the failure to display the glass image icons?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Their icons are font based.  Make sure you include their font files and they are accessible.

If you check in your browser there are probably 404 errors trying to download those font files. Find the path that its expecting them to be, and include them there.

Here's a ticket on devextreme explaining it as well https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t756616/angular-cli-devextreme-icons-throw-the-404-error

Comment: I don't get a 404 error. I installed devexpress and the files icon are present in the path node_modules\devextreme\dist\css\icons. Now I attach to the question the images related to the unwanted situation I get